# React pass date as props : "undefined is not iterable"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web

I am a noob in React. 
I am trying to get a variable that comes from another component.

this is in a js file for the MapLeaflet component

```
const date = props => {
  return (
    props.date);
};
```

And the first component (the one where the variable is date is created) is :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import DateTimePicker from 'react-datetime-picker';
import MapLeaflets from './MapLeaflet';


class Picker extends Component {
  state = {
    date: new Date(),
  }

  onChange = date => this.setState({ date },
    function(){
      console.log("this works: " + this.state.date);
      //const DateContext = React.createContext(this.state.date);
      const DateContext =this.state.date


    })

  render() {

    return (

      <div>
        <DateTimePicker
          onChange={this.onChange}
          value={this.state.date}
        />
         { console.log(this.state.date) }
         <MapLeaflets date = {this.state.date}
         />
         )}         
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Picker;
```

Here is my log error :

> TypeError: undefined is not iterable (cannot read property
>   Symbol(Symbol.iterator))

[image]
I have extensively searched stackoverflow. This appears to be a pretty simple problem, yet it does not work here. I can read use child/parents, or context, but i did not manage to make it work. I did not try redux, but i guess this would be overkill to just pass a props.

Any observation or suggestion would be valuated.

---

### EDIT

Thanks for your answer. Actually the error log comes from this line in the first component :

```
 <MapLeaflets date = {this.state.date}
 />
```

Does anybody knows why it does not work ?

I am editing also to include a part of the mapleaflet component, just so you understand what i want to do with this date.

```
  refreshStationsList() {
    const { updateFavStationsList, readStoredFav } = this.props;
    // console.log('refresh');
    const date = (props) => {
  return (
      <div>{props.date}</div>
  )
}
const request = `https:url`+date;
this.setState({ isLoading: true });

const favStationsId = readStoredFav();

axios.get(request)
  .then(result => {
    const stationsList = result.data.map(
      station => {
        const isFavorite = favStationsId.includes(station.number);
        return { ...station, isFavorite: isFavorite }
      }
    );
    this.setState({
      stationsList: stationsList,
      isLoading: false
    })
    updateFavStationsList(stationsList);
  })
  .catch(error => this.setState({
    apiDataError: error,
    isLoading: false
  }));
  }

  render() { ....etc
```

Answer (score 3):

Your MapLeaflets component should look like this

```
const MapLeaflets = (props) => {
    return (
        <div>{props.date}</div>
    )
}

export default MapLeaflets;
```

Comment: Thanks @iamwebkalakaar !  I actually edited my question to show where i want to include the date : in an url. I tried your way, but i got the same error ! Let me know if i am doing something wrong

Comment: Actually this is this line in the first component that generates the error <MapLeaflets date = {this.state.date}
 />. don't know why.

Comment: You are getting this error because you are using `map function` on undefined.
Make sure you are getting `res.data` from your api

Comment: Where do I use map function? And date is not undefined. Actually even with <MapLeaflets name="this is a string" /> , it gives the same results. A string is not undefined

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to loop on `undefined`, first make sure that you are getting data from your api. and always try to do type check before proceeding.
You can use `typeof` to do type check

Comment: its a string. Actually even with <MapLeaflets name="this is a string" /> i get the exact same error